# Redis DEL vs LRU Eviction?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

If I am using redis to check whether a unique message has been handled historically or is currently being handled (for preventing Pub/Sub duplicate message handling), and I am not expecting to read this kv pair ever again, should I bother deleting the kv pair at the end of the message handler, or just let the LRU eviction eventually delete it? The processing of the message would take far longer than the delay between duplicate messages.

For context, this is some JS pseudocode of what the processing looks like:

```js
// Message comes in
const messageHandler = (message) => {
  const duplicate = checkMessageInRedis(message.ID)
  if (duplicate) return
  registerMessageInRedis(message.ID)
  // ... do some stuff to the message
  deleteMessageInRedis(message.ID) // DO I BOTHER WITH THIS??? OR LET EVICTION DELETE IT?
}
```

I guess the question becomes: Is an eviction delete more resource intensive than a DEL transaction? And if so by how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach would be to provide a TTL (time to live) when adding the message to Redis.

i.e.   registerMessageInRedis(message.ID, ttl)

This will auto-delete the message after ttl expires and will save from an additional network round trip cost for explicit delete.